# Unable to install 64 bit os

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, windows-installation

I have a GA-78MLT-USB3 motherboard with AMD FX 4300 processor with Windows 7 32 bit.

I was trying to install Windows 10 64 bit, but am unable to do so as there is a pop up showing as 'your current version of Windows 32 bit does not match the architecture of 64 bit installation media.

System:

```
Manufacturer    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Model   GA-78LMT-USB3 6.0
Total amount of system memory   8.00 GB RAM
System type 32-bit operating system
Number of processor cores   2
64-bit capable  Yes
```

Storage:

```
Total size of hard disk(s)  931 GB
Disk partition (C:) 432 GB Free (466 GB Total)
Disk partition (D:) 133 GB Free (466 GB Total)
Media drive (E:)    CD/DVD
```

Graphics:

```
Display adapter type    ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics
Total available graphics memory 1662 MB
      Dedicated graphics memory 512 MB
      Dedicated system memory   0 MB
      Shared system memory  1150 MB
Display adapter driver version  8.970.100.1100
Primary monitor resolution  1360x768
DirectX version DirectX 10
```

Network:

```
Network Adapter Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

Comment: Try to install with Bootable media. Not through 32bit Windows

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade from a 32-bit edition to a 64-bit edition of Windows. You have to do a clean install. You need to backup your data, boot the computer from the installation medium and choose a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade to a 64-bit OS on a system with a 32-bit OS, you have to do a full install.

Comment: The system report says that the processor is 64 bit capable

Comment: Ok, your question says 32 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to upgrade an installed 32 bit Windows (7, 8 or 8.1) to a 64 bit Windows 10.

You can either uninstall the old Windows version (or format the disk partition it's installed on, erasing all the data on it) or install Windows 10 side-by-side in a new partition.